# Model Performance not improving

Tags: python, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, model-evaluations, gnn

I am currently working with a GNN (a Graph attention Model) based model and the main task is to do Graph prediction. My model doesnot improve its performance when I change the number of heads or the learning rate as if the results cached, the results seem to be the same. The only way that the results change is by using

```
# Shuffle dataset
```

`torch.manual_seed(12345)`
`dataset = dataset.shuffle()`

I commented this line of code, but I am still getting the same results associated with this seed value, when I randomly change this value (just pick a random value) the accuracy changes sometimes to the worst and other times to better results. I dont understand why the model doesnot improve its performance when I change the number of Heads or layers or learning rate